# GBQ BQ-CLI Export CSV to Google Storage with query and specified delimiter

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to export a table from Google Bigquery into CSV and save the file into a google storage using `bq extract` but the issue is I want to export that table into 2 CSV files with different filters, and also using `;` as delimiter for my CSV file. But I cannot find any documentation online where I can use queries with `bq extract`.

For example, I have table `mytable.cities` and I would like to export that table into 2 CSV files: the first CSV file I want export the table with a condition `where city = 'Los Angeles'` and for my second CSV with `where city = 'New York'`.

My syntax currently is this:

```
bq extract --destination_format=CSV --field_delimiter=';' mytable.cities gs://myBucket/myFile.csv
```

I did not use the command `bq query` because it doesn't give me the option to change my delimiter to `;`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do this is to write a code that uses BQ API to run your queries and then use GCS API to save the results as CSV. See code below to do this:

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud import storage

bq_client = bigquery.Client()
gcs_client = storage.Client()

bucket = gcs_client.get_bucket("your-bucket-name")

query_1 = """
    SELECT mascot_name,mascot FROM `bigquery-public-data.ncaa_basketball.mascots`
    where non_tax_type = 'Devils'
"""

query_2 = """
    SELECT mascot_name,mascot FROM `bigquery-public-data.ncaa_basketball.mascots`
    where non_tax_type = 'Dragons'
"""

df_1 = bq_client.query(query_1).to_dataframe()
bucket.blob("devils.csv").upload_from_string(df_1.to_csv(index=False,sep=";"),"text/csv")

df_2 = bq_client.query(query_2).to_dataframe()
bucket.blob("dragons.csv").upload_from_string(df_2.to_csv(index=False,sep=";"),"text/csv")
```

NOTE: The example above used a public dataset to test the query and import to csv.

See bucket after code is ran:

[image]

Sample file content (devils.csv):

[image]